# Where create cookie that holds only user id in Zend MVC project?

Tags: zend-framework, cookies, zend-framework-mvc

I am working with Zend MVC project.
MY mission: add cookie that will have only user unique id.

**Problem:I don't know where create a cookie.**

Options to place create a cookie, that I thing about:

1. bootstrap.php init()/run()
2. index.php (not make sense)
3. In Controllers

**My project structure**:

application/bootstrap.php

public/index.php

---

Please help me, if you can give example it will be great.

Thanks,
Yosef

Comment: Is there a reason you want to use a cookie and not a variable stored in a `Zend_Session` somewhere?

Comment: I would use an FrontController Plugin

Comment: Hi ArneRie, thanks! Can you please give example?

Comment: How do you get a user id, if the user is not identified? :? Also, look at `Zend_Session` and `rememberMe()`.

Answer (score 0):

I've put it in the Bootstrup.php, I just created new method called _initUserUniqueId:

```
protected function _initUserUniqueId(){

    $uniq = uniqid();
    if(!isset($_COOKIE['f_uniq'])){ 
        setcookie('f_uniq', $uniq, time() + 60 * 60 * 24 * 365, '/');
    }
}
```